# wordpress contact form 7 issues - How to track leads that come from which contact form if we have so many contact forms

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

My website has so many wordpress contact forms to collect the leads...I want to create a form class or form id in order to differentiate from which contact form i am getting the leads or which contact form is my customer using to submit the details...Please help me in this matter

Comment: Why do you have so many forms? Are they all different? Maybe you could use one form with conditional logic..??

Answer (score 1):

I think hidden fields can help you do this. Simply add a hidden field (example below) to each of your contact forms.

```
[hidden name default:name "Your Form Name or ID"]
```

You can find more info here: https://contactform7.com/hidden-field/